# Basis swap pricing dynamics

Tags: pricing, liquidity, risk-premium, basis

The existence of basis spreads leads to that e.g. a 6M forward rate has a different price than two after each other following 3M forward rates. This due to that the 6M forward rate has a higher credit and liquidity premium.

Can someone explain why? As I see it, the money is locked in 6 months in both contracts and therefore should have equal credit and liquidity risk. Is this because the demand and supply of 3M contracts is higher than the 6M?

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the underlying index 3M Libor and a 6M loan that pays a compounded 3M interest. A 3M Libor is by definition the (average) rate on an interbank 3M loan. A 6M loan, regardless of its reference interest rate, is subject to counterparty risk up to 6M.

Comment: Let me clarify: If we disregard LIBOR, and only consider two 3M rolling FRAs vs a 6M FRA. Equal cash flow amounts and timings. Why does the 6M contract have a higher yield?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question. how do you define the yield on an FRA ?

Comment: The return I would get if I invested some quantity of money in the contracts. So I claim that if I invested £1 in both contracts, I would get a higher return from the 6M FRA.

Comment: an FRA is worth zero when you enter into it and does not require an initial investment, it is just a swap between a reference index (Libor 3M, Libor 6M, ...) and a fixed rate. The actual return you would get is the difference between the realized Libor(s) and the fixed rate. The expected return is zero in both cases.

Comment: Ah yes, "return" is incorrect terminology. Let's modify the example: say that the first FRA has 3M LIBOR index, rolling over two periods. The other FRA has a 6M LIBOR index, one period. In my view, the credit and liquidity premia on both the indices are the same. Why is the swap rate of the 6M indexed FRA higher than the 3M?

Comment: In the case of an FRA, again it is just a swap so the fixed rate will be the expectation (under the risk neutral measure) of the floating rate.

Comment: But I think I see where are you are confused. Consider the following strategies 
(a) you lend 1 to a BB rated bank at 6M Libor and after 6 months you get 1 + 6M Libor if the bank has not defaulted.  
(b) you lend 1 to a BB rated bank at 3M Libor and after 3 months you get 1 + 3M Libor if the bank has not defaulted. At this point you have the choice of not lending, lending again at 3M Libor to the same bank if its rating is unchanged, or lending at 3M Libor to another BB rated bank. (a) and (b) do not bear the same liquidity and counterparty risk, hence the difference in rates

Comment: Now if instead of (b) you choose (c) lending to the BB rated bank for a maturity of 6 months at a compounded 3 month floating rate then that rate should compensate you for 6 month liquidity and counterparty risk, so it should be equal to 3M Libor + $x$, with $x$= 6M vs 3M Libor spread. This will be equivalent to (a).

Comment: Now we're on the same page! I'm comparing (a) vs (c) but saying that they're not equivalent and that the swap rate of (c) will be higher than (a). This is because the xIBOR market became segmented by tenor after the subprime crisis because they bear different credit and liquidity risk. See for example https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.2770.pdf The study proves this but I'm trying to understand why

Comment: I think (a) and (c) are equivalent because with (c) you receive 3M Libor + (6M Libor vs 3M Libor spread) = 6M Libor. In another words if you lend for a locked maturity of 6 month to a BB bank but with quarterly interest the synthetic rate will be equivalent to 6M Libor.